# How can I reference figure*'s subfigure?

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, subfloats

I'm writing a paper to submit a conference.

However, I am having some problems fixing non-resolved references in latex.

```
\begin{figure*}[ht!]

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}

    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{fig/toy}

    \vspace*{-1cm} % for cosmetic change

    \label{fig:toynetwork_example}

    \caption{A toy network}

\end{subfigure}%

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}

    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{fig/exampleProcedure13}

    \vspace*{-1cm} % for cosmetic change

    \label{fig:firstIterationFin}

    \caption{After first iteration}

\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}

    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{fig/proposed_adjacency_matrix}

    \vspace*{-0.4cm} % for cosmetic change

    \label{fig:proposed_adjacency_matrix}

    \caption{Adjacency matrix}

\end{subfigure}%

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}

    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{fig/proposed_influence_matrix}

    \vspace*{-0.4cm} % for cosmetic change

    \label{fig:proposed_influence_matrix}

    \caption{Influence matrix}

\end{subfigure}%

    \hspace*{0.2cm}

\vspace*{0.3cm} % for cosmetic change

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}

    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{fig/proposed_update_order}

    \vspace*{-0.4cm} % for cosmetic change

    \label{fig:proposed_update_order}

    \caption{Update order}

\end{subfigure}%

\caption{Example network}

\label{fig:example_network_procedure}

\end{figure*}
```

The PDF file shows `??` rather than the reference.

Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: What is the reference that you are missing? Or is all of them? In addition, try placing the label command just after the includegraphics command.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 7):

The `\label` must go ***after*** or ***inside*** the `\caption` command. It ***cannot*** be placed before. This is because `\caption` increments the relevant counter, which is what `\label` hooks onto. If you put the `\label` first, there is nothing onto which it might hook.

For example, turning your code into a (semi-)Minimal Working Example by adding a preamble and substituting standard images:

[image: labelled subfigures]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\ref{fig:example_network_procedure}
\ref{fig:firstIterationFin}
\ref{fig:proposed_adjacency_matrix}
\ref{fig:proposed_influence_matrix}
\ref{fig:proposed_update_order}
\ref{fig:toynetwork_example}

\begin{figure*}[ht!]
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a}

    \caption{A toy network\label{fig:toynetwork_example}}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a}

    \caption{After first iteration}\label{fig:firstIterationFin}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a}

    \caption{Adjacency matrix}\label{fig:proposed_adjacency_matrix}
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a}

    \caption{Influence matrix\label{fig:proposed_influence_matrix}}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a}

    \caption{Update order}\label{fig:proposed_update_order}
  \end{subfigure}

  \caption{Example network}
  \label{fig:example_network_procedure}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```