# How to separate between the reference of figure and subfigure?

Tags: cross-referencing

In this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256404/how-can-i-reference-figures-subfigure) and its answer, the reference is shown like 1b. I want the reference to be shown like 1-b. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/423080/133968

```tex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@subfigure}{\thefigure-} % <-- modify the figure number "prefix"
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        A subfigure
        \caption{Subfigure}
        \label{subfig}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Figure}
    \label{fig}
\end{figure}

\cref{subfig}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering.

Comment: I don't want the "fig." part. What should I do?

Comment: @Mina, use `\crefname{subfigure}{}{}` in the preamble (see section 8.1.2 of [`cleveref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) manual). However, personally I feel removing it would only make your work tougher, unless you have a very strong reason to do so.